# how to get column define which is calculate with mysql function in java

Tags: java, mysql

eg:

```
`select t1, t2, sum(t1,t2) as t3 from table1`
```

or

```
`select t1, t2, concat(t1, t2) as t3 from table1`
```

I can get the column define of t1/t2 by using

`select column_type from information_schema.COLUMNS where column_name = 't1'; // eg:varchar(20)`

but how can i get the column define of t3?

thx~

Answer (score 1):

The column defined using `as` are just displayed on runtime. There's no storage of such columns in database. This is known as column Alias. refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) for more information relevant to Column Alias.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such function in MySQL. As I understand you want something like pg_typeof function in postgre. The only way I can think of is to store the select in a temporary table and then describe that table. You can create a table from select.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable1 AS
select t1, t2, sum(t1,t2) as t3 from table1;  --Add limit 0 here maybe to make it faster

DESCRIBE tempTable1;
```